# Launcher doesn't respect TMPDIR

Tags: unity, 11.10

In my `.bashrc`, I define `TMPDIR=${HOME}/tmp` so temporary files are under my encrypted `$HOME`. `emacs`, invoked from the launcher, doesn't see this definition, but `emacsclient`, invoked from a shell does.

So far, I know that
`emacs` (after `(server-start)`) opens a socket in '/tmp', 'emacsclient' tries to communicate with 'emacs' over a socket in '${HOME}/tmp', and does very poorly. How can I presuade the launcher (via emacsclient.desktop?) to pass the right value for TMPDIR?

Comment: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ tells me I can't use .desktop files ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the variable definition in `.profile` instead of `.bashrc`. The latter has a statement near the top that causes it to exit very early when executed by a non-interactive shell. Log out and back in to see whether it works.

Also don't forget to add `export` like this:

```
export TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp"
```

If that doesn't work, modify the launcher (it's in `/usr/share/applications`) so that its Exec line says:

```
Exec=sh -c 'TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp" emacs'
```

Comment: Putting the definition in ~/.profile worked! Thanks. It's a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can't pass my `TMPDIR` in to the `emacs` `server-start` function, so I guess I'll have to make `emacsclient` use `/tmp` to hold the socket.

In my `.bashrc`:

```
export EDITOR="env TMPDIR=/tmp emacsclient"
export VISUAL="env TMPDIR=/tmp emacsclient"
```

but that seems sub-optimal. Any suggestions?