# Emacs 24 can't find ls

Tags: 11.10, emacs

I installed `emacs-snapshot` through http://emacs.naquadah.org/

Everything works fine except when I run `dired`
I get this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Searching for program" "no such file or directory" "ls")
call-process("ls" nil nil nil "--dired")
```

Comment: Are you starting emacs through the Dash launcher? If so, it is using the PATH defined in `~/.profile`, not the one set up in `~/.bashrc`. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/64005/launcher-doesnt-respect-tmpdir for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this with:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/bin")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path is probably wrong. I use cygwin for 64 bit processors. Change your configuration as in the following picture:
[Settings of CYGWIN's environment variable on Windows 10.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By10n.png)
Pay attention to two lines from the two windows. For one thing CYGWIN is set as an **environment variable** via windows 10 settings. Put both the root folder and the bin folder's local address there. Lastly, open the environment variable PATH by double clicking on it and add a new line. Just type %CYGWIN% just like how I did in the picture above.