# Emacs 24.3 won't lock to unity bar

Tags: 12.04, unity, emacs

I'm running a Ubuntu 12.04. I just installed emacs 24.3 from [Damian's Cassou's emacs PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs).

Before I doing this, I completely removed all emacs with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove emacs*
```

Not sure if this was a good or bad thing. Next I opened emacs and I locked it to the unity bar. However, whenever I open a new script another emacs "thumbnail" appears on the unity bar.

How do I get emacs to stay locked on the Ubuntu unity bar?

Comment: which version of emacs is running? from the terminal you can type `emacs --version`. I ask because you may have to run `purge` instead of `remove`

Comment: GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1

Comment: if you don't get any better suggestions, try removing the ppa and purging emacs* and the start the ppa procedure over again.

Comment: alright I'll try that

Comment: It didn't work =/ thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41539/how-can-i-make-running-emacsclient-from-the-unity-launcher-reuse-an-existing-ema?rq=1 Not sure if it is a dupe.

Comment: Did you at least look at the link I provided above and try the answer suggested there before cross-posting to SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995902/emacs-24-3-wont-lock-to-ubuntu-unity-bar

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I deleted the cross-posting to SO. I did the the steps in the link just now. It solved the problem. thanks you

Comment: Do I know where I can get the new unity icon used for Emacs 24.3? I tried looking for the .png/.svg for it online earlier but couldn't find it.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear that solution worked for you. Thanks for submitting that last comment as a new question.