# Ubuntu 16.04 emacsclient -c Desktop Application not working

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher, emacs

Dear Ubuntu Community,

my goal is it, to use emacsclient (version 24.5.1) as a default editor in Ubuntu 16.04. If I double click on a text file, emacsclient opens new frame quickly. If the the the daemon is not running, it will start one.

If I run my emacsclient command (emacsclient -c -a="") in the terminal, everything works fine. If I start emacs the first time, it will start emacs-server even though I do not run emacs-server in my .emacs/.init file. If the daemon is already running emacs opens a new frame. But I want to use emacsclient in my GUI (Unity) as well. According to [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient#toc4) I added the following text to ~/.local/share/application/emacsclient.desktop:

> [Desktop Entry]
>   Name=Emacs (Client)
>   GenericName=Text Editor
>   Comment=Edit text
>   MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
>   Exec=emacsclient -с -a "emacs" %F
>   Icon=emacs
>   Type=Application
>   Terminal=false
>   Categories=Development;TextEditor;Utility;
>   StartupWMClass=Emacs

And also added:

> export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
>   export EDITOR="emacsclient -c"
>   export VISUAL="emacsclient -c -a emacs"

to my ~/.bashrc

When I now right-click on a text file in can choose to open it with "Emacs (Client)". The launcher symbol appears, but no frame opens. After like 10 seconds the symbols disappears again. If I go back to emacsclient.desktop and change the Execline to:

> Exec=emacsclient -a "emacs" %F

it will open the file accordingly; meaning if no daemon is running, it starts emacs. If an emacsclient is already open, it will open the file in the already existing frame similar to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41539/how-can-i-make-running-emacsclient-from-the-unity-launcher-reuse-an-existing-ema/41705#41705).

What am I doing wrong, or is the -c option not compatible with desktop applications?

Greetings,
Andi